# Query on CMake double colon in target name after vcpkg install of SDL2

Tags: c++, cmake, vcpkg

Installing SDL2 using vcpkg on Windows concludes by advising that CMake's `find_package` should be used in "Config" mode; and shows an example `target_link_libraries` invocation using `SDL2::SDL2` and `SDL2::SDL2main`. I'm not familiar with "Config" mode, nor these double colon names. I'm typically looking for `PACKAGE_INCLUDE_DIRS` and `PACKAGE_LIBRARIES`. So my first question is, assuming the double colon names somehow provide the `target_link_libraries` with the library paths, *how do I provide the include paths* to the compiler?

Secondly, on Ubuntu, CMake warns that policy CMP0028 is not set; which relates to the double colon names. Using Make then produces two errors - that it cannot find `-lSDL2::SDL2` and `-lSDL2::SDL2main`.

I'm looking to use vcpkg to prepare a range of libraries across a Windows lab for my C++ graphics students. A number of students also appreciate it if our example project codes can also work on Linux.

My CMake version on Windows is 3.12.1; 3.10.2 on Ubuntu; and vcpkg was built from the github repo clone yesterday (21/08/18).

Comment: The include paths are automatically set. `target_link_libraries` handles all usage requirements, not just linked libraries

Comment: You can provide CMake a hint where to find the SDL package and its config file by adding its installation path to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH on the command line, e.g. `cmake .. -G "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64" -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=C:/SDL2` Mostly packages are installing their config files under <installdir>/lib/cmake/ . And regarding to the include files: SDL2::SDL2 and SDL2::SDL2main are symbolic targets and also carry information about the include path. Adding a target_link_library dependency also adds their include paths to the target being build.

Comment: @vre With `vcpkg` the folder structure is not the same. It won't be c:/SDL2.

Comment: @drescherjm Did not know that, thanks. The installation path `C:/SDL2` was a rough guess by me, so adapt that if necessary.

Comment: vcpkg creates binaries in vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/bin. Here is some info on integration with CMake. https://blog.kitware.com/vcpkg-a-tool-to-build-open-source-libraries-on-windows/

Comment: Thank you all. Any thoughts on the errors on Ubuntu?

Comment: Are you including the vcpkg.cmake toolchain file on the CMake command line in Ubuntu too?

Comment: No. As `find_package` (in normal "module" mode) find SDL2 on Ubuntu, I had thought it might also work in "Config" mode too? I'd rather not install vcpkg on Ubuntu, so perhaps I must resort to `if` clauses for Ubuntu/Windows?